# Bluetooth Low Energy - Android scanFilter not working

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have two Android devices communicating using BLE. One is adverting while the other is scanning and receiving. When I advertise using a Service UUID, the other device will pick it up just fine. However, when I filter by Service UUID, the scanning device won't pick up the advertisement at all. Both devices are using the exact same UUID to advertise/scan. The scanning device is running 5.0.1. This is the code I have set up for the scanfilter:

```
P_UUID = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("6be5ab1b-328b-4709-a737-84db596e10d2"));
B_scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(P_UUID).build();
        list = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
        list.add(B_scanFilter);
```

On the advertising device, this is the code I have for the AdvertiseData:

```
//The random UUID is just a placeholder. Using P_UUID for both the serviceUUID and serviceDataUUID doesn't change anything
B_advertiseData = new AdvertiseData.Builder().addServiceUuid(P_UUID).addServiceData(new ParcelUuid(UUID.randomUUID()), getByteArray(data)).build();
```

And finally, here is the scanCallback and startScan code:

```
 B_scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Received Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Received Data(Batch)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Scan failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Scan Error: " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
        }
    };



B_scanner.startScan(list, B_scanSettings, B_scanCallback);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Scan Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Note that with B_scanCallback, none of the methods are called during scanning(even onScanFailed()).
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated! If you want me to post more of the code, I can do that. I only posted the code that I think could be causing this problem.